# Adding Text under each image in image gallery

Tags: html, css, image

I tried using p tag with max-width attribute but in doesn't worked for me:

```
.a {
     max-width:100px;
}
```

With HTML:

```
<p class="a">Hello Welcome to Stackoverflow.</p>
```

I want this text to be fit under image of resolution 500*500. If the text goes more than image width it should be automatically wrapped in next line.

Comment: Hi Akash, welcome to SO. Please take a moment to look into this to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know is this what you need, just check this snippet

```css
.image_wrap {
  width: 300px;
}
.image_wrap img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_wrap">
 <img src="http://dreamicus.com/data/garden/garden-06.jpg" alt="garden" />
 <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if this is what you need please tick the answer as usefull

Answer (score 2):

Use This Code

```css
div {
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div>
  <img src="img.jpg" />
  <p>Hello Welcome to Stackoverflow</p>
  </div>
</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.
It works fine for me.

```css
.resized_anchor {
  max-width: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>question reality.</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div>
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSpMXZY5KMRLpo8vbVxizv5SiRdX2AXeM1lkT-7dXTL2D5el7UHZ59GHWc" height="100px" width="100px" />
  <div class="resized_anchor">
   <a href="#">Hello Welcome to Stackoverflow. Doing a greate job here</a>  
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```